# In MongoDB, possible to affect 2 items to a '$ne' operator?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find all phones that are **not** `"samsung"` or `"iphone"`, the following code doesn't work:

```
find({'phone':{'$ne':'samsung','iphone'}})
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator:

```
db.collection.find({'phone': { '$nin': [ 'iphone', 'samsung' ] } })
```

This will select all phones that are not "samsung" or "iphone"

Answer (score 0):

You can use not in `$nin` operator.

```
find({'phone':{'$nin':['samsung','iphone']}})
```

[Details $nin operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)